# If Statements To Find Area and Perimeter

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
print "This is to find the area or perimeter of a rectangle "
print "Do you want to find the area(a) or perimeter(p) of your rectangle?"
a= raw_input(" I want to find the ")
if raw_input = (a)
        print "What is the length of the rectangle?"
        b = int(raw_input("The length of the rectangle is "))
        print "What is the width of the rectangle?"
        c = int(raw_input("The width of the rectangle is "))
        d = (2 * b) + (2 * c)
        print d
if raw_input = (p)
        print "Got it. What is the length of your rectangle?"
        x = int(raw_input("The length of the rectangle is ")) 
        print "What is the width of your rectangle?"
        y = int(raw_input("The width of the rectangle is "))
        z = x * y
        print z
```

How can I program the code to say that `a` is the area and `p` is the perimeter?

Comment: Does your area check perimeter and perimeter check area?

Comment: i dont understand what you mean...

Comment: Are you also looking for [string formatting in python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)?

Answer (score 2):

This is odd, you cannot check to see if `raw_input()` is something. And also, it is `==` to test for equality, `=` is to assign. Here is what you want:

```
print "This is to find the area or perimeter of a rectangle "
print "Do you want to find the area(a) or perimeter(p) of your rectangle?"
a= raw_input(" I want to find the ")
if a=='p':
        print "What is the length of the rectangle?"
        b = int(raw_input("The length of the rectangle is "))
        print "What is the width of the rectangle?"
        c = int(raw_input("THe width of the rectangle is "))
        d = (2 * b) + (2 * c)
        print d
elif a=='a':
        print "Got it. What is the length of your rectangle?"
        x = int(raw_input("The length of the rectangle is ")) 
        print "What is the width of your rectangle?"
        y = int(raw_input("The width of the rectangle is "))
        z = x * y
        print z
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing your checks wrong. In python a `=` means assignment whereas `==` is a test for equality. Try this instead:

```
print "This is to find the area or perimeter of a rectangle "
print "Do you want to find the area(a) or perimeter(p) of your rectangle?"
a= raw_input(" I want to find the ")
if a=='a':
    print "What is the length of the rectangle?"
    b = int(raw_input("The length of the rectangle is "))
    print "What is the width of the rectangle?"
    c = int(raw_input("THe width of the rectangle is "))
    d = b*c
    print d
elif a=='p':
    print "Got it. What is the length of your rectangle?"
    x = int(raw_input("The length of the rectangle is ")) 
    print "What is the width of your rectangle?"
    y = int(raw_input("The width of the rectangle is "))
    z = 2*x+2*y
    print z
```

Comment: Your indenting is wrong for the `if` statements. And you still have single equals signs. And your area `if` statement checks perimeter, and your perimeter `if` statement checks area. :)